# Array with random integers

Tags: java, arrays, random

I need and array that generates 10 random numbers between 1 and 5,
inclusive. I then need to display the number of times 1-5 shows up in the array. This is what I have so far, it runs fine, it's just that the number of occurrences for the numberes 1-5 totals different everytime, which it should total exactly 10 everytime since the array can only hold 10 integers.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //create an array that will produce 10 numbers
    int[] randArray = new int[10];

    //initialize randArray to the values 1-5
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        randArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Number\t" + "Appears");

    for(int x = 1; x < 6; x++){
        System.out.println(x + "\t" + randArray[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you populating only 6 random numbers?

Comment: You are printing the array values themselves, not the count. You're aren't actually counting anywhere in your code.

Comment: Okay, none of this is helping, perhaps I need to explain more. I need an array that holds 10 integers and each slot can only hold the numbers 1,2,3,4, and 5, and they need to fill the array at random so the numbers generated might be: 5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1. Then I need to show the numbers that can only be put into the array, 1-5, and show how many times each number appears in the array like so: Number 1 Appears 3 times, Number 2 Appears 0 times, Number 3 Appears 3 times, Number 4 Appears 2 times, and Number 5 Appears 2 times. everytime the total of *appears should equal to 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Confusing limit on size-of-array with random-range

Your `for` loop addresses only the first six slots in your array rather than all ten, index # 0 through # 5 = 6 slots, not 10.

## Use named variables

You may have been confusing your limit on the random number generator with your limit on the size of the array. This is a good example of why one should use well-named variables rather than [“magic” numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

```
//create an array that will produce 10 numbers
final int countElements = 10;
final int randomRange = 5;

int[] randArray = new int[ countElements ];

//initialize randArray to the values 1-5
for ( int arrayIndex = 0 ; arrayIndex < countElements ; arrayIndex ++ ) {
    randArray[ arrayIndex ] = ( int ) ( Math.random() * ( randomRange ) ) + 1;  // (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}

System.out.println( "Number\t" + "Appears" );

for ( int arrayIndex = 0 ; arrayIndex < countElements ; arrayIndex ++ ) {  // Start at zero, not one, as arrays are accessed by index (zero-based counting).
    System.out.println( arrayIndex + "\t" + randArray[ arrayIndex ] );
}
```

```
Number  Appears
0   3
1   2
2   3
3   3
4   3
5   2
6   4
7   5
8   5
9   3
```

## `ThreadLocalRandom`

Generally better, and simpler, to use the [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) class rather than [`Math.random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()).

This class uses the *Half-Open* approach to defining a range, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. If you want results to include only 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, specify range of 1-6.

```
int randomRangeHalfOpen_Origin = 1 ; // We want results generated in range of 1-5 in fully-closed range, which is 1-6 in half-open range, ending is exclusive). 
int randomRangeHalfOpen_Bound = 6 ;  // The limit is *exclusive* (never appearing in generated results). This is known as "Half-Open" approach to defining a range. This is often the wisest approach in defining ranges.
… 
randArray[ arrayIndex ] = 
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 
        randomRangeHalfOpen_Origin , 
        randomRangeHalfOpen_Bound 
    ) 
;  // Returns a pseudorandom int value between zero (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).
```

## Counting occurrences

As for counting the number of occurrences amongst the generated random numbers, I will leave that to the author to finish their own homework assignment. And already covered many times on Stack Overflow if one bothers to search.

Answer (score 0):

The loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    randArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * (6 - 1)) + 1;
}
```

Doesn't initialize 10 but only six random numbers since there is `6` as the limitation for the loops count. Then you print only 5 array elements since you loop indices from `1...5`. Arrays are indexed from 0. Use the following `for-statement` for both of the loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }
```

A final note: The better way without casting to generate a random integer between 1 and 5, both inclusive is:

```
Random r= new Random();
for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    randArray[i] = 1 + r.nextInt(5); // 5 is exclusive, the nearest lower possible int is 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code :

First

> I need and array that generates **10 random numbers** between 1 and 5

in this case you have to loop until 10 which is the **array length** so instead of :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
```

You have to use :

```
for (int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++) {
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Second

> ... then need to display the **number of times 1-5 shows up in the array**

To display the frequency of each value 1-5 you can use this way with Java 8 :

```
Map<Integer, Long> appearence = Arrays.stream(randArray).boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> n, Collectors.counting()));
```

to display the result you can use :

```
System.out.println("Number\t" + "Appears");
appearence.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "\t\t" + v));

Number  Appears
1       2
2       2
3       4
4       2
```